# Alignment in a piecewise function

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment

I would like to have the following two equalities displayed with the `=` aligned.  I use the following code.  The `=` are not aligned, and `2.5pt` is typeset before the `=` in each line! Also, there is an unseemly amount of space between the left brace and the first equality.  (The cases environment gives "the right" space between the left brace and the first equality, but it does not align the `=`.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\left\{
\begin{array}{c@{2.5pt}c}
a^{3} + b^{3} &= -q \\
ab &= \dfrac{-1}{3} \, p
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use `aligned` rather than `array` here, because semantically it's not really a `cases` situation nor an `array`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
a^{3} + b^{3} &= -q \\
ab &= \dfrac{-1}{3} \, p
\end{aligned}
\right.
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The column separation specification `@{<stuff>}` inserts `<stuff>` between the columns, so the result is as expected in your case. If you want a `2.5pt` gap, then you need to insert `@{\hspace{2.5pt}}`.

However, if your main aim is to align the parts at the `=` sign, then you can use

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \left\{
    \begin{array}{c@{}c@{}c}
      a^3 + b^3 &{}={}& -q \\
             ab &{}={}& \dfrac{-1}{3} \, p
    \end{array}
  \right.
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: maybe `r@{}c@{}l` ?

Comment: I set the column space using the command "\setlength{\arraycolsep}{2.5pt}" and, as you suggested, I used "rcl" in the mandatory argument for the align environment. I would like to thank @Werner for his help, too.

Comment: I have one other comment about this display. I like the spacing between the left brace and the beginning of the longer equalities in the cases environment. The space is significantly bigger using the array environment. You can see that in Werner's display.  The code that @Trold gives uses the array environment, but the display that LaTeX typesets does not give too much space between the left brace and the first equality.  Why are these different?

Comment: A manual tells the syntax to eliminate the space that is inserted between columns in an array environment from the beginning of the first column. "With @{} before the first column and after the last column, the the additional space \arraysepcol is not used." So, here is the code for the array environment that I want.  \begin{equation*}\setlength{\arraycolsep}{2.5pt}\left\{\begin{array}{@{}rcl} a^{3} + b^{3} &=& -q \\ ab &=& -\dfrac{1}{3} \, p\end{array}\right.\end{equation*}

Comment: @user143462: My suggested use would be `@{}r@{}c@{}l` (or just `\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}` and also `&{}={}&`, since it provides the correct spacing around the math relation `=`. In your `@{}rcl` case the `=` would be spaced very wide.

Comment: By the way, Mico informed me that lengths in terms of em can be specified in the array environment.  Since LaTeX puts 5mu of space about the equals sign, 18mu=1em, and 5/18 = 0.27777, issuing the command \setlength{\arraycolsep}{0.2778em} and issuing the mandatory argument {@{}rcl} for the array command in the array environment also gives the proper spacing.

Answer (score 1):

When I tried using `cases`, it aligned nicely and worked just fine:

```
\[
  \begin{cases}
    a^3+b^3 &= -q \\
    ab      &= -\dfrac{1}{3}\,p.
  \end{cases}
\]
```

If that isn't an answer and you really are stuck with using the `array`, you might try to change the column separator to an equals sign with a bit of space around it, and then put `@{}` before the first column to fix your problem with too much space:

```
\[
  \left\{ 
  \begin{array}{@{}c@{\;=\;}c} 
    a^{3} + b^{3} & -q \\
    ab            & \dfrac{-1}{3} \, p
  \end{array}
  \right.
\]
```

[image: comparison of two pieces of code]

Comment: I forgot to specify that I wanted each equality to have the typical 5 mu space about the equals sign. Thanks for telling me about putting "@{}" before the first column to suppress the extra space.  I know the array environments puts space - I think the default is 5 pt - between columns.  It is odd to me that it puts this space before the first column and after the last column.

Comment: @user143462, I've changed the `\,`s to `\;`s, which will (er, should, I think...) give the spacing used around a binary relation like =.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using the `empheq` package for a simpler syntax, with option `overload`. It loads `mathtools, which in turn loads`amsmath`. I also use`nccmath` for its mediumsized fractions, that look better here, in my opinion:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[overload]{empheq}
\usepackage{nccmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}[left = \empheqlbrace]
a^{3} + b^{3} &= -q \\
ab &= -\mfrac{1}{3}\, p
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I should be more familiar with the array environment. So, I am going to use Werner's code.  I like your display, too. What is the "empheq" package?

Comment: It's a component of the `mh` bundle, along with `mathtools` (a must) and a few others. It's dedicated to `emph(asise) eq(uations) hence its name — coloured background, adding things on the left as here or on the right, boxing equations.  As you can see the syntax is simple: you use the usual amsmath environment, and you have an optional key-valued systeM. You should take a look at the documentation to see what you can do with it.